# Construct variadic template argument list

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, duktape

Say i have the following scenario:

```
namespace detail
{
    using duk_c_function_t = std::function<duk_ret_t(duk_context*)>;

    template<typename T_Return(typename ... T_Params), std::function<T_Return(T_Params)>
    duk_ret_t duk_function_proxy(duk_context* ctx)
    {
        const int n = sizeof...(T_Params); //real number of arguments passed.
        duk_idx_t num_arguments = duk_get_top(ctx); //Number of arguments from javascript
        int x = duk_require_int(ctx, 0); //Get integer -> parameter no 1
        const char* c = duk_require_string(ctx, 1); //Get string -> parameter no 2
    }
}
template<typename T_Return(typename ... T_Params)>
duk_c_function_t duk_function(std::function<T_Return(T_Params ...) function_item)
{
    return duk_c_function_t(detail::duk_function_proxy<function_item>);
}
```

Where `duk_function` returns a function of the signature `duk_ret_t function(duk_context* ctx) { ... }`. Now, i know how to call the function object in `duk_function_proxy` with the variadic templates and such. But there is one problem for me: The javascript interpreter i am using requires that, for every c-function i want to expose, i need query the parameters from the stack, as shown in `duk_function_proxy`. However, with that being the case,  i dont know how to call the function object - i can only store the queried parameters in some sort of container, and thus i cannot call the function object with the given signature. Is there any way to store my queried parameters in some sort of container, and then unpack and pass it to the function object as parameters? I query the required parameters based on the variadic template list, as seen in the prototype.

## In short:

I want to iterate over T_Params, get and store the corresponding variables using `duk_require_*` (in some sort of container), and then use those values to call the function object, which is passed as a template argument.

Comment: i can't quite work out what you want to do. can you simplify the question a little? Is it that you want to iterate over the TParams, getting arguments from duk_require(0...n-1) and check that they all exist?

Comment: i want to iterate over the params, get and store the corresponding values (in some sort of container), and then call the function object (which is passed as a template argument) using those values.

Comment: got it - will post a solution in 5 mins

Comment: You should lay them into a tuple first.  Iterate over the tuple through recursion.

Comment: @TrevorHickey managed to avoid that - you can use std::tuple_element<N> of an uninstantiated tuple, since the two parameter packs are not being evaluated in deduced context. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get you started. I've simulated the DUK interface since it's not installed on my machine but you'll get the idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

struct duk_context;

const char* duk_require_string(duk_context*, int i)
{
    static constexpr const char * strings[] = {
        "i like",
        "hairy",
        "ducks"
    };
    return strings[i];
}

int duk_require_int(duk_context*, int i)
{
    return i * 6;
}

template<class Type> auto get_arg(duk_context* ctx, int i) -> Type;

template<> auto get_arg<std::string>(duk_context* ctx, int i) -> std::string
{
    return duk_require_string(ctx, i);
}

template<> auto get_arg<int>(duk_context* ctx, int i) -> int
{
    return duk_require_int(ctx, i);
}

template<class...Args, size_t...Is>
void get_args_impl(duk_context* context, const std::function<void(Args...)>& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<Args...>;
    f(get_arg<std::tuple_element_t<Is, tuple_type>>(context, Is)...);
}

template<class...Args>
void get_args(duk_context* context, const std::function<void(Args...)>& f)
{
    get_args_impl<Args...>(context, f, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
}

void foo(std::string a, int b, std::string c)
{
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    duk_context* ctx = nullptr;

    get_args(ctx, std::function<void(std::string, int, std::string)>(&foo));

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
i like 6 ducks
```

Comment: im confused. that is, templates are way more complicated than i thought :D

Comment: @calcyss :) you'll get the hang of it in a few years

Comment: is it  possible to pass the function objects as a template argument? i ask because the `duktape` interface only accepts the signature `duk_ret_t function(duk_context*)` for exposing, which i would've retrieved using the `duk_function` and `detail::duk_function_proxy` methods.

Comment: You can only pass types and constants as template arguments, not objects. You have to either pass objects as function arguments or as data members of an object.

Comment: oh, shoot. then my concept above wouldnt work at all? Well time to rethink everything...

Comment: The trick with templates is to take it one step at a time. Build up your logic using layers of very simple meta functions or template functions. Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks! i think it'll take a lot of desperation and tea though :P. i am trying to write a C++ wrapper for a JavaScript interpreter called duktape, which only has a C-API. So its kinda like LuaBind/Lua.

Comment: haha... im freaking out over here. Im desperately to come up with a new design... well thanks again for your answer :)

Comment: @calcyss if you're still stuck in a day or two you can mail me on hodges.r@gmail.com and I'll give you a hand. I enjoy template programming.

Comment: Well, im not to sure but i remembered that there are lambda closures in C++11... i think those can help me. Maybe this kind of project is too big for me, im new to templates :)

Comment: @calcyss you're simply looking to expose c++ functions to javascript in a safe way? You're on the right track. Variadic template expansion can help you whether you used closure, std::function or std::bind. Just take it one step at a time.

Comment: ive sent you a mail btw :) ive hit the line with regarding my ideas.